# Span and Smallest Submodule Proof

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing, modules

Let R be a ring, M a R-module, and $X \subseteq M$

Show that span$(X)$ is the smallest submodule of R containing X.

My ideas: Every submodule is contained in its span so $X \subseteq$ span$(X)$ and $x \in X \subseteq$ span(X) but now I need to show that it's the smallest... how do I go about showing this?

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Let $J$ be any submodule containing $X$. Then show that $J$ contains span$(X)$.

This is not very difficult: use the definition of span($X$) to show that since $J$ is a module containg $X$ it should contain span$(X)$.

Comment: One could also proceed to show that the intersection of submodules of $M$ is again a submodule, and take the intersection of all submodules of $M$ containing $X$, and show that this is $\text{span}(X)$.  That this submodule contains $\text{span}(X)$ is trivial.  To show that it is contained in $\text{span}(X)$, one simply needs to notice that $\text{span}(X)$ is a submodule containing itself, so it would be one of the submodules in the intersection used to define the smallest submodule containing $X$.  (I think this works...)